# Unable to launch IE browser using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: selenium, iedriverserver

I am trying invoke IE browser using Selenium Webdriver and have used the below code to invoke:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", driverPath+"IEDriverServer.exe");
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

But while execution I am getting error as below:

```
Started InternetExplorerDriver server (64-bit)
3.4.0.0
Listening on port 3210
Only local connections are allowed
Dec 12, 2017 6:29:04 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
Dec 12, 2017 6:29:07 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Falling back to original OSS JSON Wire Protocol.
Dec 12, 2017 6:29:07 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Falling back to straight W3C remote end connection
Exception in thread "pool-1-thread-1" org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities [{ensureCleanSession=true, browserName=internet explorer, version=, platform=WINDOWS}], required capabilities = Capabilities [{}]
Build info: version: '2.42.2', revision: '6a6995d31c7c56c340d6f45a76976d43506cd6cc', time: '2014-06-03 10:52:47'
System info: host: 'PCXXXXXX', ip: 'XX.XXX.XXX.XX', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_141'
Driver info: driver.version: InternetExplorerDriver
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:91)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:241)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:227)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.run(InternetExplorerDriver.java:180)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.<init>(InternetExplorerDriver.java:172)
    at org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver.<init>(InternetExplorerDriver.java:144)
    at com.cognizant.framework.selenium.WebDriverFactory.getWebDriver(WebDriverFactory.java:76)
    at supportlibraries.DriverScript.initializeWebDriver(DriverScript.java:301)
    at supportlibraries.DriverScript.driveTestExecution(DriverScript.java:155)
    at allocator.ParallelRunner.run(ParallelRunner.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Please let me know if there is some additional settings that I have missed. System IE browser version: 11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Internet Options, select 'Security' Tab. Check that 'EACH' zone (Internet, Local Intranet, Trusted Sites, Restricted Sites) has 'Enable Protected Mode' enabled. This will likely require an IE restart.

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing "\" in the path

try

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", driverPath+"\IEDriverServer.exe");
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try with the below options

1. Change the Web driver opened IE browser zoom to 100%
2. Navigate to Internet Options -> Security and unselect Enable protect mode for all the zones